# How to add an JPanel from an other class to an existing Frame

Tags: java, swing, class

I have my MainWindow class where menue buttons and everything else are. In the middle of it is an Panel called content. I want to load JPanels from other classes into this field. But when i start the code below nothing shows up.

MainWindow Class:

```
    public class MainWindow {

    private JFrame frame;

    private JScrollPane Content;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    MainWindow window = new MainWindow();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public MainWindow() {
        initialize();
    }
    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        frame.getContentPane().add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JPanel TopPanel = new JPanel();
        scrollPane.setColumnHeaderView(TopPanel);

        JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("Made by " + Globals.Author);
        TopPanel.add(lblNewLabel);

        JButton btnHome = new JButton("Home");
        TopPanel.add(btnHome);
        btnHome.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                Content.add(new Home());

            }
        });

        Content = new JScrollPane();
        scrollPane.setViewportView(Content);
    }

}
```

JPanel Class:

```
    public class Home extends JPanelContentTemplate {
            /**
             * Create the panel.
             */
            protected void InitializeComponents(){
                setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));

                JPanel OptionsMenuePanel = new JPanel();
                add(OptionsMenuePanel, BorderLayout.WEST);

                JPanel ConentPanel = new JPanel();
                add(ConentPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                ConentPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 2, 0, 0));

                JLabel lblConnectedWith = new JLabel("Connected With:");
                ConentPanel.add(lblConnectedWith);

                JTextPane textServerIP = new JTextPane();
                ConentPanel.add(textServerIP);
            }

            @Override
            protected void Refresh() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
}
```

The InitializeComponents method comes from an Self Created Superclass:

```
public abstract class JPanelContentTemplate extends JPanel {

    /**
     * Create the panel.
     */
    public JPanelContentTemplate() {
        InitializeComponents();
    }

    protected abstract void InitializeComponents();
    protected abstract void Refresh();
}
```

I also tried an repaint etc.

Thanks for Help

Comment: You really should name your variables according to the Conventions... first letter always lowercase!

Comment: i know but in c# its otherwise and the code is for myself so i just use one standard...

Comment: But you're **not** "coding for myself" when you post your code and ask questions about it here. Out of respect for the volunteers here and elsewhere who help you for free, your posted code *should* conform to standards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing shows up because you add nothing but empty JScrollPanes to your GUI:

```
Content = new JScrollPane();
scrollPane.setViewportView(Content);
```

Comment: Thank you!! That was what i missed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example of adding separate panels to the MainFrame.  I hope it helps you.

```
public class SidePanel extends JPanel {

    private JLabel label;

    public SidePanel() {

       setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());

       label = new JLabel("Hello");

       setVisible(true);
       /* More Code Goes Here */
    }
}

public class CenterPanel extends JPanel {

      /* Center Panel Code */

}

public class MainFrame extends JFrame {

     private SidePanel sidePanel;
     private CenterPanel centerPanel;

     public MainFrame() {

         setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
         setLayout(new BorderLayout());

         sidePanel = new SidePanel();
         centerPanel = new CenterPanel();

         add(sidePanel, BorderLayout.WEST);
         add(centerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

         setSize(300, 300);
         setVisible(true);
    }
}

/* Main App */
public static void main(String [] args) {

    try {
                                       /* Lambda Expression */
        SwingUtitlities.InvokeLater(() -> new MainFrame());
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```